# Using vibrations in a "custom" way

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to write an app that uses vibrations as notificatons. A certain amount of vibrations means a certain thing.

I've managed to cleverly put together a method that does a series of short vibrations contionusly. But I'm having trouble just doing X# of vibrations...

Here's my code

```
- (void)goVibration {

    if(vCount > 1)

    {
          vCount--;
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    [self delayCallback:^{

        AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

        [self goVibration];

    } forTotalSeconds:0.3];
    }
}
```

vCount = 8 before the function is called.
I only get 3 vibrates in this situation.

If I take out the if(vCount > 1) the function calls infinitely. Any ideas?

Here is my delayCallback

```
- (void) delayCallback: (void(^)(void))callback forTotalSeconds: (double)delayInSeconds{

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if(callback){
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe I can use the Taptic Engine?

Comment: you should add your code for delayCallback. Possible the issue is there.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if you get a notification when I edit my post, so I'm just notifying you here..